# Exponential matrix decay

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

I’m working on contractive systems that have a system of ODE equations.
I have an exponential matrix multiply by time that is for a given matrix $A$ I’m getting $e^{At}$.
I want to know what are the conditions on $A$ such that the exponential will decay as $t$ goes into infinity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find the answer in more or less any book on ODEs and dynamical systems, such as [the one by Teschl](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/).

I think that the decay in matrix norm of $e^{At}$ is equivalent to the fact that all eigenvalues of $A$ have strictly negative real part. But please double check in the book above.